# Wrapping in while loop is creating extra div

Tags: php

I have this code that's creating an extra empty div when there are extactly 3, 6, 9, etc items.

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    echo '<div class="three-item-wrapper">';

    if( have_rows('upcoming_stops_asia') ): while ( have_rows('upcoming_stops_asia') ) : the_row();
    ?>

    <div class="item">Content</div>

<?php

if($i % 3 == 0) {echo '</div><div class="three-item-wrapper">';}

$i++; endif; endwhile; endif;

echo '</div>'; 

?>
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ending the current div and starting a new one when you get to a multiple of 3. If there are no more after that, then the div will of course be empty. One solution would be to accumulate the results and output them in a div only as required:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('upcoming_stops_asia') ) {
    $results = [];

    while ( have_rows('upcoming_stops_asia') ) {
        the_row();

        // Add to the collection of results
        $results[] = '<div class="item">Content</div>';

        if( count($results) == 3 ) {
            // Output three results and reset
            echo '<div class="three-item-wrapper">' . implode($results) . '</div>';
            $results = [];
        }
    }

    // Output any additional results; no div generated if there aren't any
    if( !empty(results) ){
        echo '<div class="three-item-wrapper">' . implode($results) . '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your missing a few ending quotes `implode($results) . '</div>;`, I thought about editing them in, but alas I was too lazy... :)

Comment: Thanks, fixed it!